# WCF in binary legacy environment

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization, wcf-binding

We are writing C# client which should connect to old legacy servers. To be extensible in the future we would like to utilize WCF framework.

The old legacy protocol is proprietary & binary one. To integrate into WCF we would like to replace the usual XML serializer into our proprietary binary format marshaller. Pay attention we do not want to encapsulate the  XML into some other transport protocol but to completely replace the XML serializer as irrelevant. Think about WCF talking to CORBA (but not CORBA really) server which does not understand any HTTP/SOAP/MTOM/...

Can someone point us to the example on how to do it

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is a WCF custom channel.  Have a look at the following post which includes some links that I believe will be helpful for what you wnat to do:

[How to write a socket based Custom Transport for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381142/how-to-write-a-socket-based-custom-transport-for-wcf)

Comment: How this will help? you mean to accept the serialized xml passed to transport layer and try to re-serialize into our format?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that can't be done (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

If you want to write your new client in C# to use WCF then you will have to build your WCF service to read from the legacy protocol, essentially acting like a bridge.